# How to call created widget object in other widgets in QT

Tags: c++, qt

In my application I'm having three widgets, I created the objects for all widgets in `main()` function, but I don't know how to call the created objects in other widgets, please guide me, I create the objects like this:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "widget.h"
#include "one.h"
#include "two.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  Widget *w = new Widget();
  One *one = new One();
  Two *two = new Two();
  w->show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

How can created objects call other widgets?

Comment: What do you mean exactly for "call created objects"? something like `one->show();` ?

Comment: You should update your question to be more clear. However, as I understand it there is nothing Qt specific in this question. For example, if you want instances of `One` or `Two` to be used/callable by `Widget` instances then they should be passed to a `Widget` instance, be members owned by `Widget` instances, etc...

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to 'call' them, but to connect them through the Qt [signal slot mechanism](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html):

```
class One : public QObject {... boilerplate omitted
public slots:
   void slotWithVoid(){ emit slotWithInt(1); }
signals:
   void signalWithInt(int); // filled in by Qt moc
};

// note: give your widgets an owner
auto *w = new QButton(&app);
auto *one = new One(&app);
auto *two = new Two(&app);

connect(w, &QButton::click,
        one, &One::slotWithVoid);

connect(one, &One::signalWithInt,
        two, &Two::slotWithInt);
```

Now when something happens (e.g. a button click), Qt event system will take care that your objects are called in the right order, from the right thread, safely, etc...

Comment: Without more information it's not possible to know whether `One` or `Two` are even derived from `QObject`.

Comment: @JamesAdkison: let's say it's an educated guess.  There is no formal proof, but I doubt any is needed :)

OP is working in the Qt application framework.  Objects should be Qt objects.  Otherwise the question should be tagged 'C++ objects' or something.